# Rails: List only direct subclasses of ActiveRecord::Base subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, subclass, single-table-inheritance

I am trying to get all the direct subclasses of a class that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base;` that is, only classes that inherit directly from the base class, not subclasses of subclasses. But the normal way of doing this does not appear to work with `ActiveRecord::Base` subclasses.

Normally, this is done using the `Class::subclasses` method:

```
class C1; end
class C2 < C1; end
class C3 < C2; end
C1.subclasses
#=> [C2]
```

I want to do this for an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass:

```
class T1 < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class T2 < T1; end
class T3 < T2; end
T1.subclasses
#=> [T2(Table doesn't exist), T3(Table doesn't exist)]
```

I get both the child and grandchild classes, which is not what I want! The same fundamental behavior occurs for classes that do have tables defined.

Already, this points out that `ActiveRecord::Base` subclasses act a little differently in that inspect() is overridden to provide the table name. So it's not too far a stretch to guess that they overrode subclasses as well.

1. Is it possible to get a list only of the direct subclasses of an
   `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass?
2. And why did they change `subclasses()`?

Comment: that's strange, `subclasses` is actually defined in active_support and is not part of ruby. if you use ruby internals you would use `ancestors` to walk the dependency hierarchy. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d47b90e76c989a8f0ca32c140e9b7220da0e5edc/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/subclasses.rb#L35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/subclasses/class

`ActiveRecord::Base` had a `subclasses` method that simply returned the value of `descendants` until version 3.1 (actually this says 3.0.9, but I think this is when it was deprecated; you can see it in the source code until 3.1). `descendants` returns everything that is `<` the receiver (the behavior you observed).

Here is the commit that removed it:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9b610049bb4f73dbcdc670879683ec2a1a2ab780

Rails 3.1 and after should behave as you describe. If you are using Rails >= 3.1, then I'm not sure how to explain what you are seeing.

Comment: Rails 3.0.3, so that explains it. It's interesting because subclasses is defined by something from Rails, as @phoet above pointed out, and so it must have different definitions in different places. So I tried this:  
    `class T1 < ActiveRecord::Base`  
    `def subclasses`  
    `method = Object.singleton_class.instance_method(:subclasses)`  
    `method.bind(self).call`  
    `end`  
    `end`  
Unfortunately, that didn't work, and produced the same results as before.

Comment: And that's because it needs to be def self.subclasses, and then it works! Thank you!!

Comment: My only thought to add would be that you might consider calling your method something else in case Rails needs that method on subclasses of `ActiveRecord::Base` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Reposted code from my comment above because comments don't allow good formatting. This works for my purposes:

```
class T1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.my_subclasses
    Object.singleton_class.instance_method(:subclasses).bind(self).call
  end
end
```